# Where are my notifications?

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox

In [my inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/7562599/laurel?tab=inbox) it alleges the most recent comment directed at me was posted [6 hours ago](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/215443?noredirect=1), but I noticed there are more recent comments under that and also under a [different answer of mine](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528708/what-is-the-history-of-may-being-used-to-mean-must/528709#comment1290451_528709) that I was not notified for.

I’m not sure if there are more notifications beyond these that I should have gotten.

(I originally noticed this on the app, but it’s the same on the website. Also note that reputation notifications still work for me.)

Does anyone else see this happening? Also can we get this fixed soon?

Comment: Note there's a recent Math meta question [Missing Notifications for Comments on a Question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31388/602049) that is likely also related to your issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A regression bug was introduced here that prevented *some* (but not all) comment notifications from going out. The issue has been fixed.

Unfortunately there is no practical way for us to requeue the comment notifications that didn't get sent out in the past few hours.